# Azure App Service encountering inconsistent HttpClient request failures

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, dotnet-httpclient

We have an Azure App Service which is making calls to a third party API. Occasionally, and seemingly randomly, requests to this third party API will fail and then immediately begin working again. Roughly 20% of requests are failing. The third party are claiming that they have no issues on their end.

The code making the request is this:

```csharp
try 
{
  // simplified
  var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage
  {
    RequestUri = new Uri(requestUri),
    Method = HttpMethod.Get
  };
  httpRequest.Headers.Add("username", username);
  httpRequest.Headers.Add("token", accessToken);
  response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest);

  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); 
}
catch (Exception ex) {
  _logger.Log(ex)
}
```

Also note that the HttpClient is using pooling, defined in `Startup.cs`:

```csharp
var jitter = new Random();
var retryPolicy = HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError()
    .OrResult(msg => msg.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)) + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(jitter.Next(0, 500))); // exponential backoff + jitter to prevent grouping

var sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri(_config.BaseUri));
sp.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 60 * 1000;

services.AddHttpClient<IFooService, FooService>(client =>
{
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
}).SetHandlerLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)).AddPolicyHandler(retryPolicy);
```

The exception, when it occurs, is this:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled. 
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
   at Polly.Retry.AsyncRetryEngine.ImplementationAsync[TResult](Func`3 action, Context context, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ExceptionPredicates shouldRetryExceptionPredicates, ResultPredicates`1 shouldRetryResultPredicates, Func`5 onRetryAsync, Int32 permittedRetryCount, IEnumerable`1 sleepDurationsEnumerable, Func`4 sleepDurationProvider, Boolean continueOnCapturedContext) 
   at Polly.AsyncPolicy`1.ExecuteAsync(Func`3 action, Context context, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean continueOnCapturedContext) 
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.PolicyHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
```

Note that at the time the app service fails, any requests sent via Postman work correctly, implying a network level issue in the app service.

I've seen similar questions regarding Azure Web Service/HttpClient issues suggest this is a SNAT exhaustion issue, however the Azure diagnostics tool states that SNAT is not a problem and is well within limits - see the image below:

[image]

Can anyone tell me why the app service would randomly prevent HttpClient requests, and how I can determine if this is the issue, and correct it.

Comment: how many requests do you send? Is it happening only under heavy load or is it a random problem?

Comment: also, are you making _httpClient static or disposing it?

Comment: `how many requests do you send?` It varies by user demand, average around 1/min - certainly nothing excessive. `only under heavy load or is it a random problem?` Random, no correlation with demand. `are you making _httpClient static or disposing it` it's injected via DI using the HttpClientFactory (following [this pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests#how-to-use-typed-clients-with-ihttpclientfactory)), demo code in the startup.cs snippet above

Comment: which SKU is associated to your app service plan? (b1, f1, s1, etc) ?

Comment: It's currently a single S1 instance.

Comment: my guess it's something related to Service Point Manager, but I'm not 100% sure about it...

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio thanks for the suggestion, I'll have a look in to it